# Draw on Geotiff file and export the GPS coordinate list/array

Tags: python, gps, gdal, geotiff

I just want to draw paths or poly-lines on **Geotiff images** and export the corresponding GPS coordinates-[lat,long] of the selected points.

Comment: you must give more information. What library are you using for display and paint this? where is your code?

Comment: @Zharios  Sorry for not writing all the information,  Actually i was looking for an algorithm or method to do this, i don't know what libraries to use to draw and obtain the coordinates needed. I have no experience in GIS. Earlier my approach was to draw on google maps using its API in JavaScript and obtain the waypoints. i did that, But then i felt its not a good idea and started looking for this method. I need the waypoints for Autonomous GPS navigation.

Comment: i suggest that if you go to use Python, you take a look at QT Framework [link](https://www.qt.io/). This could help you to draw Shapesfiles and raster.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zharios, im working on it. I also found this qt library https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qml-location5-maps.html, do you think this is suitable?

Comment: i have not used this library but you can try it. if you do not see it viable you can try use QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItems.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more how it can be done? for example a small algorithm. The file necessarily doesn't have to be Geotiff, i can use any drone imagery, Geotiff is only an option. The point is to extract the GPS coordinates of the path I'm drawing on the file. I'll be using these coordinates for navigation of vehicles along same path.